# Issue while iterating a json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

From the Ajax call I am getting the following JSON response.

```
    studentList:
{
"currentStudent":0,
"totalStudent":11,
"studentDetails": 
    [{
     "adId":1,
     "adName":"BMB X5",
     "sfImage":{
            "imageName":"Desert",
            "imagePath":"/images/updatedUI/companylogo.png",
            "ext":null
           }
    }]}
```

Now I wanted to print the studentName and Phone number in the `console.log()`
I have iterated the loop and able to print the studentName in the console, To print the Phone number I tried the Nested loop still facing some issues with printing the Phone number in the console.

My code is:

```
var data = studentList.studentDetails;
for (var key in data) {         
    console.log(data[key].studentName); // Here Student Name is printing            
   }
```

How can I iterate inside the loop and print the phone number in the console?

Comment: try `data[key].address.phone`

Comment: You don't need a loop at all..? Just use `studentList.studentDetails.address.phone`

Comment: first of all it is json object not array, studentDetails.address.phone will give you phone number

Answer (score 0):

easy way

```
 var data = studentList.studentDetails;
 for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++) {         
     console.log(data[i].adName); // Here Student Name is printing            
 }
```

Comment: just do `console.log(StudentList)`  and update your question with that. The json you have provided in question is an object, not an array.

Comment: still it is not an array,  array will be in square brackets  `[ .. ]`, your object looks like an object.

Comment: Student name is printing with my code also. I am unable to print the Phone number. Can you please suggest How can I print Phone number

Comment: `data[i].address.phoneNo` must be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. It loops over Iteratively and prints all the data

```
function iterateObj(data) {

    for (var key in data) {

       if (typeof(data[key]) == "object" && data[key] != null) {
           iterateObj(data[key]);
       } else {
           console.log(key + "  :  " + data[key]);
       }
    }
}
```